# google directions json empty but only in explorer

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting the data variable filled with the correct response data in all browsers but ie.
In all versions of ie, the response is empty..?

```
function getDirections(addr) {
    var %id%url = encodeURI("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions      /json?origin=" + addr + "&destination=%id=maplocation%&sensor=false");
    alert(%id%url); // looks good
    $.getJSON(%id%url, function(data) {
    alert(data); // empty in all versions of ie.. works in al other browsers
        if(data.routes[0]){ //... and so on
```

Comment: `%id%url` is not exactly a valid variable name. this code could not possibly work in ANY browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you hit the problem that [Google has dropped support for IE 8](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/google-drops-support-for-ie-8-windows-xp/).

Comment: Absolutely correct. I had been misled by a customer saying all versions. I just tested in ie9 and 10 and it works. just pre ie9 does not. Thank you.